# CorelDraw - end line at the circle edge

Tags: shapes, corel-draw, line-art

I have a round (circled) area and on it a few lines that end on the end of the circle. As you can see the line doesn't end in the shape of the circle. I made a square around the circle and erased the circle out then used Object, Shaping, Front minus back (with line and the shape marked), but it gives the result on the picture below (straight cut).
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is:
[image]

Is it even possible to make this kind of cut, and if it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options.

1) Put the lines behind the black circle.

2) Put the lines inside the colorfull circle (white) with Power Clip.

3) Convert the lines to path (Ctrl+Q) and then cut them with the black circle. (I am not sure what is the name of the Window because I am not using the last version of Corel and mine is in spanish, but it is a dockable window > Give shape or Shaping > Trim)

*You need to extend a bit further the gray line so that gap does not show.